# How to send data to PC quick and easy without using API

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter application that is meant for collecting data on road usage, and I would like to carry out analysis after collection of data.

I've saved the file and I am able to read the file via readAsString and writeAsString to

```
'data/user/0/com.example.flutter_example_app/app_flutter/fault_report.txt'
```

How can I access the data quickly and easily without having to integrate too much stuff [For instance, opening an API and writing to cloud and etc]?

The app is supposed to be just a collection method and all analysis will be carried out afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how ofter you would like to retrieve your data. If you only want to get the data once in a while, you can use File Explorer, Bluetooth file sharing, Cloud Drive or etc. to retrieve your data. But if you want to retrieve data more often, making some simple api will not take too much time.

Comment: Hi, in the end, I chose to use Google Cloud, it is indeed not that hard to connect to it. Thank you